# Retain value in the textbox untill user type

Tags: textbox

I want to create a title textbox like on this site. When a user focuses nothing happens, and when a user types in textbox all is removed.

Comment: What programming/scripting language are you using? *"Send me the script for this"* — Have you tried your browser's "View Source" command instead?

Comment: <sadface> I vote for 'send me the code/script for this' to be blacklisted! lol

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are taking about html + javascript/jquery

Check this : [Create an ASP.NET TextBox Watermark Effect using jQuery](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=427)

or

Sample script using jquery

```
$().ready(function() {
  swapValues = [];
  $(".wm").each(function(i) {
    swapValues[i] = $(this).val();
    $(this).focus(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == swapValues[i]) {
```